# Two threads and two DataContexts inserts twice

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a application that uses EF6 ORM.

I have a method that creates a new object. I also have a thread that is responsible of the app logging. It Enqueues LogObject and saves it to the database every 5 seconds..

So. A user calls the method to create the new object:

```
using(DataContext context = new DataContext() {
   context.MyObjects.Add(new MyObject() { prop1 = "test" });
   context.SaveChanges(); // save #1
   Log("A new MyObject was created!"); // this method enqueues log info
}
```

The logger database saving method is as follow:

```
private void Flush() {

     using (DataContext db = new DataContext() {
         foreach(Log l in _logs) {
            db.Logs.Add(new LogObject() { propX = "blabla" });
         }
         db.SaveChanges(); // save #2
    }
}
```

The save #1 inserts the object properly.
The problem is that the save #2 also inserts an identical MyObject()....

I profiled the database and debug the processes.

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful. This could happen if 'save #2' involved the object you saved in 'save #1' - that doesn't seem to be the case from your question, but it's probably not the real code.

Comment: Does `LogObject` have any navigation properties on it (To `MyObject`, perhaps)?

Comment: @BradleyUffner That was the problem. Log had a navigation property to MyObject... Thanks!

Comment: I would give answer credit to Francisco's answer.  He got it right (indirectly) even though the example code left out the navigation property that was the cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see a behavior like this, consider that the object is not being tracked by the context. You are creating a context and disposing it so the object is probably not tracked and for EF it's considered a new object, that's why it is inserted again.

You should attach the object again so EF tracks it and knows it's not a new object.

Answer (score 0):

Put them in the same context maybe? In my understanding you would only log what is going in to the db.... that would not require a "timer function". Or choose another ORM where you have more control...